# Counting the number of days logged in per month

Tags: mysql, authentication, count, unix-timestamp

I built a table in my database that inserts the login number and a timestamp upon successful login to the site.

I am inserting the data via `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`

I now need to construct a query to count the number of logins for each user in a given month..  the kicker is that I only want to track the number of days that the user logged in in a given month, not the actual login count number.

This is the query I have started with, but I dont need a count of total logins, just a count of days per month that each user logged in:

```
SELECT login, COUNT(DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(datestamp)))
FROM logincount
GROUP BY login
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you want [`COUNT(DISTINCT)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct).

Also, if you want a count per month, you can add the [`MONTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function into your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
    login,
    MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(datestamp)) AS MonthOfYear,
    COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(datestamp))) AS DaysInMonth
FROM logincount
GROUP BY login, MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(datestamp))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT login,count(a) FROM (SELECT login, DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(datestamp) AS a FROM logincount) sq GROUP BY login;
```

to get the count of days for each login.